# How do i strip all info of a type in C++?

Tags: c++, types

Lets say i have a `static const int*const` or a `const int&`. I need the result `int` from it for use in templates. How do i strip all the data off and just get a plain `int`?

Comment: You mean how do you do a type cast?

Comment: I agree, typecast should be enough `(int)(*const_ptr)` or copy data to new variable `int tmp = (*const_ptr);` (this makes sure that you won't rewrite your variables)

Comment: @John3136: No. Literally so i can write `strip<T>::type a` with a being int when T is something like in my question

Answer (score 6):

A combination of `decay` and `remove_pointer`:

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type TStrip;
```

Comment: This answer looks like it may be better. I'd need to test later this week.

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick:

```
template <typename T>
struct strip
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct strip<const T&>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct strip<const T* const>
{
  typedef T type;
};
```

See http://ideone.com/ZNFkm

Comment: Looks good. I thought it can't be that simple (what happens if i throw in volatile) Is there no standard class i may use?

Comment: @acidzombie24 No problem either with volatile or static (they do not influence the type)

Comment: Now it's a nice answer, +1 :)

Comment: PERFECT (i think). Why am i the only one who upvoted.... oh well good answer and great example